# using lambda and groupby in combination

Tags: python

I have a dataframe df with 4 columns, lets say a,b,c,d. lets say a is the subject, b is the gender, c is the score and d is a number either 2 or
5. I would like to group the data based on subject and gender and partition this grouped data into d groups based on the score c and then store this into a new column e

this is my sample code below:

```
df['e'] = df.groupby([a,b])['c'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=np.arange(5, 0, -1)))
```

This only works if my number of categories is static and not dynamic as I would like it to be based on column d

Comment: Meaning you want to extract the value 5 from your column d? Like by taking the max of that column, storing it in a variable and using that variable instead of the two '5' in your command?

Comment: thanks very much , yes but not take the max of the column but use either 5 or 2 as specified